# Returning a object with specific property and type

Tags: javascript, types, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a function `operation` that takes two arguments `str` (a String) and `fn` (a Function).

```
function operation(str, fn){
  var temp = {}
  temp[str] = fn
  return temp
}
```

- How do you describe this return value?
- What does this return value look like in JSDoc?
- What is the example output format?

Is this acceptable for the `@return` description?

```
@returns {Object} With one key set to str and one value set to fn.
```

Is this acceptable for the `@example` output?

```
operation("foo", console.log)
// => {"foo": [Function]}
```

The main reason I ask is because I would like to use this format to test the function within a suite like [yamadapc/jsdoctest](https://github.com/yamadapc/jsdoctest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should use both of them.For exampe,in underscorejs, doc is describe as fellow:
[image]